# I should convert php json encode to Ajax array, the first time for me enough difficult to understand

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

### Controller

```
public function api_students()
{
    $students = $this->member->getStudentsPosts();

    $new_students = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($students); $i++) 
    {
        $new_students[$i]['student_fullname'] = $students[$i]->student_name.' '.$students[$i]->student_surname.' '.$students[$i]->student_middlename;
        $new_students[$i]['student_id']       = $students[$i]->student_id;
        $new_students[$i]['student_birth']    = $students[$i]->student_birth;
        $new_students[$i]['student_gender']   = $students[$i]->student_gender;
        $new_students[$i]['student_addres']   = $students[$i]->student_addres;
        $new_students[$i]['student_mobile']   = $students[$i]->student_mobile;
        $new_students[$i]['student_email']    = $students[$i]->student_email;
    }

    $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($new_students));
}
```

### Ajax

```
$('.students').click(function(){
    var student_id = $(this).attr('data-student-id');

    $.get(site_url+'/members/api_students/'+ student_id,
        function(new_students){
            $('#student_name').text(new_students.student_name);
        },'json'
    );})
```

**Problem is**, I want take information from api_students and view through ajax. Console not showing any wrong messages, it's empty so I do not know what to check. I checked api_students, here comes data, problem in my ajax code

Comment: run your controller funtion directly and check if you have any errors there.

Comment: `new_students.student_name` isn't correct according to me..can you post your JSON format?

Comment: Change it to `$('#student_name').text(new_students[0]['student_name']);`

Comment: I changed it, however same results no mistakes in the console and in the view not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

Controller

```
// get id and send array
public function api_students()
{
    $students = $_POST['id'];
  /// code 
    echo json_encode($new_students);
}
```

Ajax

```
// send data and use the result
$.ajax({
       type: "POST", 
       url: site_url+'/members/api_students/'+ student_id,    
       data:  'id='+student_id;
       success: function(stud){ 
           // use result array stud
       }
});
```

Comment: please format the code and add little bit more explanation related to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but can't put this in a comment.

As far as I can tell, your PHP block is designed to send details of a number of students over, instead of just one. If you're sending the student_id in the API call, surely your PHP code should be sending a JSON object for just a single student, not an array of them.

if you are sending an array, do your json block preparation faster and simpler...

```php
$new_students = array();
foreach ($students as $s) {
    // pre PHP 5.4 use array( instead of [...
    $new_students[] = [
        'student_fullname' => $s->student_name . ' ' . $s->student_surname . ' '.$s->student_middlename,
        'student_id' => $s->student_id,
        'student_birth' => $s->student_birth,
        'student_gender' => $s->student_gender,
        'student_addres' => $s->student_addres,
        'student_mobile' => $s->student_mobile,
        'student_email' => $s->student_email,
    ]

}
```

Comment: yeap, I have list which show base information about students with modal window. This api not only for one data table, I used that in many pages.